# Duplicate rows in csv based on match with pathname and replace constant string in each row with specified string

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, copy

I have a two-part question. I'm very new to python, so I have no idea how to even start coding this.

I want to duplicate (copy-paste) each row in a csv based on path names for images in a specified folder. Each row that matches the path name of an image in the folder must be duplicated 3 times in the csv.

Then, I want to replace the string “training/” in the first column with “training/red”, “training/green” and “training/blue” in the duplicated rows.

In the end, I want the csv to have 4 rows for each original row. One for the original path name and one for each colour (RGB).

Below is an example csv (copied directly from notepad):

```
Image,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6,x7,y7,x8,y8,x9,y9,x10,y10,x11,y11,x12,y12,x13,y13,x14,y14,x15,y15
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/DN26 female a spiracle 1.JPG,1605,1252,892,1299,1199,1557,1647,1577,1971,1428,2101,1195,1947,963,1564,838,1290,845,1208,815,1154,760,1111,632,992,601,877,639,740,853
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/Kaalplaas b 3.JPG,1789,1260,888,1288,1225,1603,1860,1560,2092,1431,2191,1186,2006,898,1750,771,1536,711,1426,659,1356,570,1259,421,1094,347,937,410,843,680
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/OP2576v__bBURF - Spiracle 2.JPG,1446,1020,594,1181,1025,1453,1525,1403,1872,1203,1936,934,1793,715,1369,547,1047,549,933,523,842,474,791,356,692,307,601,358,529,556
```

The result should look like this:

```
Image,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6,x7,y7,x8,y8,x9,y9,x10,y10,x11,y11,x12,y12,x13,y13,x14,y14,x15,y15
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/DN26 female a spiracle 1.JPG,1605,1252,892,1299,1199,1557,1647,1577,1971,1428,2101,1195,1947,963,1564,838,1290,845,1208,815,1154,760,1111,632,992,601,877,639,740,853
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/Kaalplaas b 3.JPG,1789,1260,888,1288,1225,1603,1860,1560,2092,1431,2191,1186,2006,898,1750,771,1536,711,1426,659,1356,570,1259,421,1094,347,937,410,843,680
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/OP2576v__bBURF - Spiracle 2.JPG,1446,1020,594,1181,1025,1453,1525,1403,1872,1203,1936,934,1793,715,1369,547,1047,549,933,523,842,474,791,356,692,307,601,358,529,556
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/redDN26 female a spiracle 1.JPG,1605,1252,892,1299,1199,1557,1647,1577,1971,1428,2101,1195,1947,963,1564,838,1290,845,1208,815,1154,760,1111,632,992,601,877,639,740,853
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/redKaalplaas b 3.JPG,1789,1260,888,1288,1225,1603,1860,1560,2092,1431,2191,1186,2006,898,1750,771,1536,711,1426,659,1356,570,1259,421,1094,347,937,410,843,680
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/redOP2576v__bBURF - Spiracle 2.JPG,1446,1020,594,1181,1025,1453,1525,1403,1872,1203,1936,934,1793,715,1369,547,1047,549,933,523,842,474,791,356,692,307,601,358,529,556
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/greenDN26 female a spiracle 1.JPG,1605,1252,892,1299,1199,1557,1647,1577,1971,1428,2101,1195,1947,963,1564,838,1290,845,1208,815,1154,760,1111,632,992,601,877,639,740,853
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/greenKaalplaas b 3.JPG,1789,1260,888,1288,1225,1603,1860,1560,2092,1431,2191,1186,2006,898,1750,771,1536,711,1426,659,1356,570,1259,421,1094,347,937,410,843,680
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/greenOP2576v__bBURF - Spiracle 2.JPG,1446,1020,594,1181,1025,1453,1525,1403,1872,1203,1936,934,1793,715,1369,547,1047,549,933,523,842,474,791,356,692,307,601,358,529,556
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/blueDN26 female a spiracle 1.JPG,1605,1252,892,1299,1199,1557,1647,1577,1971,1428,2101,1195,1947,963,1564,838,1290,845,1208,815,1154,760,1111,632,992,601,877,639,740,853
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/blueKaalplaas b 3.JPG,1789,1260,888,1288,1225,1603,1860,1560,2092,1431,2191,1186,2006,898,1750,771,1536,711,1426,659,1356,570,1259,421,1094,347,937,410,843,680
C:/Users/Deon Bakkes/Desktop/GTTM spiracle ML LM trial/training/blueOP2576v__bBURF - Spiracle 2.JPG,1446,1020,594,1181,1025,1453,1525,1403,1872,1203,1936,934,1793,715,1369,547,1047,549,933,523,842,474,791,356,692,307,601,358,529,556
```

Comment: Will be good to add code you've already done to question

Comment: Please also add what the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) to add prefixes to each file name. Code:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

src_path = Path(r"source.csv")
with open(src_path) as inp_f, open(src_path.with_stem(src_path.stem + "_new"), "w", newline="") as out_f:
    reader = csv.reader(inp_f)
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)
    writer.writerow(next(reader, ""))  # write header
    for row in reader:
        img_path = Path(row[0])
        if img_path.isfile():  # if file exists
            writer.writerows(([str(img_path.with_stem(p + img_path.stem))] + row[1:] for p in ("", "red", "green", "blue")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok... For anyone else who may be interested. I managed to bash through to find a solution based on making 3 separate csv's, replacing a string and recombining them. Note I'm also using tk to select folders and give the base name of the csv.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
import os
import csv

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select your directory with TRAINING images for data augmentation')

diagnostic_feature_name = tkSimpleDialog.askstring(title="Diagnostic feature",
                                  prompt="Diagnostic morphology feature name?:")

input_csv = os.path.join(folder, diagnostic_feature_name + ".csv")
output_csv_red = os.path.join(folder, diagnostic_feature_name + "red.csv")
output_csv_blue = os.path.join(folder, diagnostic_feature_name + "blue.csv")
output_csv_green = os.path.join(folder, diagnostic_feature_name + "green.csv")

#red
with open(output_csv_red ,'wb') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(input_csv,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        next(fileReader)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

text = open(output_csv_red, "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("training/", "training/red")
x = open(output_csv_red,"w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()

#blue
with open(output_csv_blue ,'wb') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(input_csv,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        next(fileReader)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

text = open(output_csv_blue, "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("training/", "training/blue")
x = open(output_csv_blue,"w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()

#green
with open(output_csv_green ,'wb') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(input_csv,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        next(fileReader)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

text = open(output_csv_green, "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("training/", "training/green")
x = open(output_csv_green,"w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()

#combine csv files

with open(input_csv,'ab') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(output_csv_red,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

with open(input_csv,'ab') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(output_csv_blue,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)

with open(input_csv,'ab') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open(output_csv_green,'r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)
```